# Will a publication of all my images slow down my app when I will have more content?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I am currently using EasySearch for my search solution for my app and I have a question on pub/sub of the search results.

Basically, the way the search works is that users will put into a search and a number of posts will be returned (I have a collections called Posts where I implemented the EasySearch).

I assumed EasySearch probably will automatically publish or subscribe depending on the results of the search queries, so I don't think I should worry about sending too many data to the client? (Correct if I am wrong).

However, the problem that I am having at the moment is that each posts is associated with a image from a collections called Images where my pub/sub is simply publish all and subscribe all from client and server and not related to the search at all.

I am just wondering does that mean I won't able to scale since I will be publishing every images to client regardless of the searches?

Post collection

```
Posts = new Mongo.Collection('posts');

Posts.initEasySearch(['firstName', 'lastName', 'degreeStudy', 'tags'], {
    'limit' : 20,
    'use' : 'mongo-db'
});

Posts.allow({
  update: function(userId, post) { return ownsDocument(userId, post); },
  remove: function(userId, post) { return ownsDocument(userId, post); },
});
```

Image collection

```
Images = new FS.Collection("images", {
  stores: [new FS.Store.GridFS("images")]
});
```

Template page for showing Search results

```
<template name="postPage">

  <div class="container">

    {{#ifEsHasNoResults index="posts"}}
      <div class="jumbotron no-results"> <h1>No results found!</h1></div>
    {{/ifEsHasNoResults}}

    {{#ifEsIsSearching index="posts"}}

        {{>loading}}

        {{else}}

        {{#esEach index="posts"}}
          {{> postItem}}
        {{/esEach}}

        {{> esLoadMoreButton index="posts"}}

      {{/ifEsIsSearching}}

  </div>

</template>
```

In short, how can I make my pub and sub of the images collections related to the easySearch result?

Comment: You should edit your question title with something more self explanatory, like "Will a publication of all my images slow down my app when I will have more content?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing the `cursor` returned by your publication with the data itself. The `cursor` is like a way to make dynamic queries without having to load all your data (unless you do load all of them using for example an `{{# each images}}`). Read [that for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30837134/what-is-cursor/30841029#30841029)

This being said (no scaling issues ahead), I assume that inside your `{{> postItem}}` template, you have an `image` helper fetching the related image in your image collection.

This will work but keep this in mind: your user can open his console and get any image in your `Images` collection simply by doing an `Images.find()` related command. So it should be ok as long as you don't have private content. However if you do, you may want to use a method to fetch your image instead of publishing/exposing the whole collection.

Comment: Thanks, a lot of clearer now, yes that is a helper finding the images depending on the userId

Comment: I'm glad I could help. Good luck with your project :-)

Comment: keep in mind that whatever the number of publication you have, it ends up in the collection they are coming from. If you have 3 pub created from the same collection, they end up merged client side. The best way to access it would then be to use one cursor per collection. This being said, and all things considered, cursor are a pretty economic way to get access to your data. Here is my opinion (not tested, I could be wrong)-> as long as you don't use too many of them (meaning let's say 25+) it should be ok. If @David Weldon or another Meteor bad-ass can confirm this, that would be helpful.

Comment: Hi apology to come back on this again, but if I have a million users, does that mean my app will return millions users image cursors?

Comment: well, no. You have one cursor for your image collection and you just use it each time you load an image. You just fetch the image related to the publication cursor when you call it in your `{{> postItem}}` template. It assumes you just use one "image" publication. My previous comment was just an answer to your generic "Does publishing too much cursors also affect performance?" question